# depending on input json array return output json in literal json in spring mvc

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

My controller

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/trans", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public  @ResponseBody String jsontest(@RequestBody String transjson) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException, JSONException {

    try{

    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    parser.parse(transjson);
    String output = null;
    JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(transjson);

    int size=obj1.getJSONArray("inArray").length();

     /* this is where I need help.*/

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    output="{\"outArray\":[{\"in\":\""+obj1.getJSONArray("inArray").get(i)+"\",\"out\":\"hie\"}]}";

    }
    return output;


    }
    catch(JsonSyntaxException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        return "{\"message\":\"Invalid JSON\"}";
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        return "{\"message\":\"Exception occured\"}";
    }
 }

}
```

what I want is if my input JSON is

```
{
"inArray": [
    "first"
]
}
```

then my output should be

```
{

"outArray": [
{
  "in": "first",
  "out": "hie"
}
 ]
}
```

if my input JSON is

```
{
"inArray": [
    "first",
    "second"
]
}
```

then my output should be

```
{
"outArray": [
    {
        "in": "first",
        "out": "hie"
    },
    {
        "in": "second",
        "out": "hie"
    }
]
}
```

means I don't know the number of the elements in the input array in the input json. And i need make my output in the literal json format on the basis of input elemen numbers as shown above.
I tried few things but have not been able to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to do this.
Actually I was trying to make string object but instead of that if I make jsonobject and put everything in it and at last return that jsonobject.tostring() form then the desired resultcan be obtained.

```
int size=obj1.getJSONArray("inArray").length();
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("in", obj1.getJSONArray("inArray").get(i));
        jo.put("out", "hie");
        ja.put(jo);
    }


    JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
    mainObj.put("outArray", ja);
    return mainObj.toString();
```